# How to copy a matrix to a larger matrix in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am a recent immigrant to the world of Python. I need to figure out how to copy a matrix to a larger matrix in Python. Let me illustrate this with an example in Matlab:

```
A = randn(4,4);
B = eye(2,2);
A(1:2,1:2) = B
```

gives

```
A = 

 1.0000          0     3.5784     0.7254
      0     1.0000     2.7694   - 0.0631
-2.2588   - 0.4336   - 1.3499     0.7147
 0.8622     0.3426     3.0349   - 0.2050
```

I am trying a similar thing with Python using NumPy in the following fashion.

```
A = np.random.randn(4,4)
B = np.eye(2,2)
A[0:1,0:1] = B
```

gives

```
ValueError: output operand requires a reduction, but reduction is not enabled.
```

Of course, the simplest way to avoid this is to use a loop but I would want to keep it vectorized.

Can someone please point me to a way of doing this without using for loops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
A[0:1,0:1] = B
```

You want:

```
A[0:2,0:2] = B
```

Why? Because Python uses half-open ranges. So the slice `[0:1]` is the half-open range `[0, 1)`, meaning just the index `0`; the slice `[0:2]` is the half-open range `[0, 2)`, meaning the indices `0` and `1`.

Comment: The NumPy user guide should really have a section on "things to know if you're coming from XXX"…

Comment: They really should. This is certainly non-obvious to me!